# How to pass props to a URL in a form with Vue.js

Tags: forms, url, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm trying to add a button that will link to a different page made to edit/delete an entry. However, the URL in the action `/videos/{the id of the video}/edit` 
Usually I would just put it in curly braces or use a template literal, but these don't seem to be working. When I try using double curly braces `/videos/{{the id of the video}}/edit` I get an error saying `Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead.`
I'm trying to pass props for the id of the video to then apply to the URL, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

I've tried template literals, but it gives me a syntax error when I try using those in `action="..."` so I tried doing what it tells me to do and use binding `:id="this.$props.id"` but I'm not sure how to then add the id to the URL without still using interpolation.

```
<form method="get" :id="this.$props.id" action="/videolist/$id/edit">
    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
```

```
props: ['id', 'name', 'description', 'category']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I ended up solving it using a template literal. It just didn't work how I thought it did. This ended up working

```
<form method="get" :action="`/videolist/${this.$props.id}/edit`">
   <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
```